# How do I create a more filtered report in Version One, similar to an excel report?

Tags: reporting, versionone

I can create a basic report I want in Version One's custom reporting tool, then export it into excel, then use filtering to drill down by specific attributes. I see no way to do this in the custom reporting module. Is there a way to accomplish this I'm missing? Am I forever reliant on excel? Or do I have to learn the API to get this done?

Comment: Can you give an example of something you've had to resort to Excel for?

Comment: I've created a report that identifies a differential between the estimated hours for a task and the actual done. Unfortunately, to filter out certain teams, in progress vs. completed, etc, requires filtering, which I can do in excel but not in Version one.